# tcpdf generated pdf file -> The file header was not found

Tags: php, pdf, html-table, html-email, tcpdf

I am trying to generate a table of user input data to SQL database to be generated into table, placed into PDF file and sent as an attachment to with an email.

All goes perfect until the point of opening. The file has 1kb inside it is only HTML code and when I tried to test it on : http://www.pdf-online.com/osa/repair.aspx it wrote this error:

> The file is corrupt and cannot be repaired, but possibly recovered
>   Errors:
>
> Open file. 0x80410104 - E - The file header was not found.
>
> File: data.pdf
>   Close file.
>
> 3-Heights(TM) PDF repair tool, evaluation license valid until unbounded

Could you please look at my code and tell me what is wrong? I tried all setting of output types (E,F,S,I etc...). None worked.

My PDF generation function:

```
function generate_pdf($ni, $na, $sur, $ma, $outp){
     if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"])){
     require_once("tcpdf.php");
        $pdf_file = new TCPDF("P", PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-16', false);
        $pdf_file -> SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $pdf_file -> SetTitle("Data o uživateli - ".$ni);
        $pdf_file -> SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
        $pdf_file -> SetHeaderFont('helvetica');
        $pdf_file -> SetFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
        $pdf_file -> SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
        $pdf_file -> SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
        $pdf_file -> SetMArgins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
        $pdf_file -> SetPrintHeader(false);
        $pdf_file -> SetPrintHeader(false);
        $pdf_file -> SetAutoPageBreak(True, 12);
        $pdf_file -> SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
        $pdf_file -> addPage();
        $data_to_pdf ='
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">Data o uživateli - '.$ni.'</h1>
            <table border="1" border-collapse="collapse" border-spacing="0" style="text-align: center;"cellpadding="10">
                <tr style="background-color: #b9b9b9;">
                    <td width="20%"><b>Název dat</b></td>
                    <td width="80%"><b>Data</b></td>
                </tr>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nick</td>
                    <td>'.$ni.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jméno</td>
                    <td>'.$na.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Príjmení</td>
                    <td>'.$sur.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>email</td>
                    <td>'.$ma.'</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>';
        $pdf_file -> writeHTML($data_to_pdf);
        ob_clean();
        $pdf_file -> Output('data_user_'.$ni.'.pdf', $outp);
    }
}
```

Function that Call the function (sets E as output type = base64 encoding chunked for email attachment)

```
$pdf_file_var = generate_pdf($ni, $na, $sur, $ma, 'E');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run clean PDF and check the output before you include the body/content.

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Output('','S');

Comment: I did that before. It worked asblank pdf. Then I added stuff and it didn't work again.